# Spring configuration in GWT Project?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, inject, autowired

I am developing a GWT-Spring-Hibernate project and I want to use Spring Autowired annotation in GWT Service Servlet but my autowired annotated service is not injected. it is null. Is there a configuration detail that I missed?

I add

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org" />
```

to my ApplicationContext.xml and I have annotated my service as @Service("myService")

```
@Autowired
MyService myService;  // This is null so WHY?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the class where the `@Autowired` annotation resides should also be in the spring context (i.e. annotated with `@Component`), but I doubt it will work if it is a GWT (i.e. client-side) class.

Comment: I have searched and found that project http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/
I will try it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to "autowire" your RPC servlets during initialization. Take a look here http://code.google.com/p/gwt-spring-starter-app/

Answer (score 1):

Is class you're trying to inject your service into actually a bean declared in Spring context? It should be, auto-wiring won't work otherwise.

It can either be declared explicitly or, provided that it's somewhere within your "com.org" hierrarchy it will be detected automatically IF it's [annotated as @Component](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) or one of other stereotypes provided by Spring.

Comment: Package for MyService is com.org and annotation by @Service stereotypes so I think it is enough to inject

Comment: I wasn't asking about MyService. A quote from above: "class you're trying to **inject** your service **into** ".

Comment: I calling MyService in GWT Servlet so you say that I have to declare GWT Servlets in Spring Context? Hmmm. I don't think so but I will try this project http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/. Thanks for your advise

Comment: I'm not saying you should declare GWT servlet in Spring context. I am, however, saying that Spring autowiring will **NOT** work unless both the bean being injected and the bean it's injected into are present in Spring context. I haven't tried spring4gwt; they may be doing behind the scenes processing of GWT servlets to make this possible.